# Running PHP on VS Code

Tags: php, macos, apache, visual-studio-code, server

I am pretty new to PHP and have been learning through various sandbox's on the internet. I am looking to start integrating it within my HTML and I have started with a pretty simple piece of code where the user types in their name and then the PHP page literally displays their name in a paragraph. I have uploaded this to my universities hosting site and it works there, but I am unsure how to get it working on visual studio code with the live server and various PHP extensions installed. I am using a Mac as well. I know PHP is server side but I thought the Live Server extension installed it would be working. Can anyone help me please, sorry if its already answered, I have had a look through and I haven't been able to find anything that's worked yet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have apache installed and a PHP server running? If so, just navigate to your server's hosting page.

Comment: I found XAMPP to be pretty easy to setup and get running personally.

Comment: The MAC has Apache and a version of PHP installed by default I think. But you will need to check and update to latest versions

Comment: VSCode is an editor (well an IDE really) its not an server in itself

Comment: I have installed apache through Brew on the terminal following this link here: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions